# How to override the custom component value in reactive form in angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, ionic5

I am having a custom reactive form component which has three inputs. Day, Month, and Year. The component works as expected except when I want in the parent to access a custom value through formControlName.value.

In the parent I have;
code

```
this.form = new FormGroup({date_of_birth: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])});
```

html

```
<dashboard-custom-date formControlName="date_of_birth"></dashboard-custom-date>
```

in the custom component I have;

```
import { Component, forwardRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  AbstractControl, ControlValueAccessor, FormControl,
  FormGroup, NG_VALIDATORS, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ValidationErrors, Validator, Validators
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'dashboard-custom-date',
  templateUrl: './custom-date.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-date.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomDateComponent),
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomDateComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class CustomDateComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor, Validator {

  dateOfBirth: FormGroup;
  errorMessages = {
    day: [
      { type: 'required', message: '* Day is required' },
      { type: 'min', message: '* Day must be between 1-31 and a valid day' },
      { type: 'max', message: '* Day must be between 1-31 and a valid day' }
    ],
    month: [
      { type: 'required', message: '* Month is required' },
      { type: 'min', message: '* Month must be between 1-12 and a valid month' },
      { type: 'max', message: '* Month must be between 1-12 and a valid month' }
    ],
    year: [
      { type: 'required', message: '* Year is required' },
    ],
  };
  public onTouched: () => void = () => { };
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dateOfBirth = new FormGroup(
      {
        day: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.min(1), Validators.max(31)]),
        month: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.min(1), Validators.max(12)]),
        year: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])
      }
    );
  }
  IsFieldValid(field: string, error: any) {
    return this.dateOfBirth?.get(field).hasError(error.type) && this.IsInvalid(field);
  }
  IsInvalid(field: string) {
    const { dirty, touched, invalid } = this.dateOfBirth?.get(field);
    return (invalid && (dirty || touched));
  }
  IsValid(field: string): boolean {
    const { valid, dirty, touched } = this.dateOfBirth?.get(field);
    return valid && (dirty || touched);
  }
  writeValue(val: any): void {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-unused-expression
    val && this.dateOfBirth.setValue(val, { emitEvent: false });
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    console.log('on change');
    this.dateOfBirth.valueChanges.subscribe(fn);
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    console.log('on blur');
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    isDisabled ? this.dateOfBirth.disable() : this.dateOfBirth.enable();
  }
  validate(c: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    console.log('Date Of birth validation', c.value);
    return this.dateOfBirth.valid ? null : { invalidForm: { valid: false, message: 'date of birth fields are invalid' } };
  }

 // custom value
  value() {
    return 'custom value';
  }
}
```

so in the parent component when I write the value, it should return me the custom component value which should be 'custom value', however, now it doesn't return me that value.

So with the formControlName.value in the parent, I should be able to access the custom value of the child. Since the child has three inputs, I want to output only one custom value.

```
console.log(this.form.controls.date_of_birth.value); //should return custom value of the child, but doesn't
```

However, now it return `{day: 'day input value', month: 'month input value', year: 'year input value'}`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access the value of any `FormControl` in the `FormGroup` you can access it using your way, i.e. `this.form.controls['date_of_birth'].value`.

But, if you need to access any property/function of the child component, you should create a new [template variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables) and access it from the component class by creating a variable with `ViewChild` decorator, like the following:

**parent.component.html**

```html
<dashboard-custom-date
  #customDateRef
  formControlName="date_of_birth"
></dashboard-custom-date>
```

**parent.component.ts**

```js
@ViewChild('customDateRef', { read: CustomDateComponent })
customDate: CustomDateComponent; // Now you can access any pbulic property/function using this variable

onSubmit() {
  console.log(this.customDate.value());
  // Now this should return `custom value` of the child.
}
```

However, you can always use the `onChange` function registered by the `registerOnChange` method, to change the form control's value to any another custom value, so you have to change the child component like the following to achieve that:

**dashboard-custom-date.component.ts**

```js
onChange: any = () => {};

ngOnInit() {
  // ....

  // move the valueChanges subscription to the ngOnInit instead of using it directly within registerOnTouched method
  // use `onChange` method to push the changes to the form-control
  this.dateOfBirth.valueChanges.subscribe(this.onChange);
}

registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
  this.onChange = fn;
}

pushCustomValueToFormControl() {
  // Always you can use `onChange` method to push any other values to the form-control like the following:
  this.onChange('custom value');
}
```

Comment: This won't help in my situation because there are other keys in the formGroup in the parent. So I am looking for universal way for all formControlName key in the parent form. I have for loop on parent keys (11 keys). I only added one custom component in here.

Comment: I am applying custom validator in the parent formGroup and I am deciding based on formControlName.value in foreach loop.

Comment: If you want to access anything from the formControlName.value, you have to include it within the value from the child component.

Comment: I couldn't get the last comment. This is what I am looking at how to override or get formControlName.value that should be my custom value in the child?

Comment: Do you mean you need to include extra properties within the value of the form-control, not only the values of the child's formGroup?

Comment: Since my custom component has three inputs (Day, Month, Year) so formControlName.value in the parent returns {Day, Month, Year}. I want formControlName.value in the parent should return my custom value of the child.

Comment: Check my updated answer now, please.

Comment: This doesn't trigger the value change & validate in the custom component. so in the parent the formControlName.value for child is always null which is the inital value.

Comment: I don’t think so, It should trigger them. Please check it again.